# How to make HTML page that doesn't brake and scroll horizontally instead when resizing browser window

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

Wondering how to make a page that doesn't break (nor shifts elements) when you resize the browser window and allows you to scroll horizontally instead.

Are the elements fixed somehow?

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why you would like to have a fixed-width website? It goes against current best practices, and violates [accessibility guidelines](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/reflow.html). I would recommend doing your best to try to make it [responsive](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Yes either make it responsive or use @media in your css depending what size you are  resizing the browser and it will reformat depending on it

*Heres a link to how to use it
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

For those who interested I found a solution. You need to set the most outer div's margin to auto and specify width in pixels

Answer (score 0):

try to use max-width. Some more information on max-width can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_max-width.asp).